# Show that $\exp(f(z)) = \frac{1}{1−z}$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, integer-partitions, egyptian-fractions

I'm self teaching Complex Analysis, and am working on this question:

Show that the series expansion of $\exp(z)$ has radius of convergence 1. Let $f(z)$ be the function to
which the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges on the domain $$D = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| < 1\}$$ Show that $\exp(f(z)) = \frac{1}{1-z}$

I've done the radius of convergence part by applying the ratio test, however, am not sure how to proceed next. Would be grateful for some guidance, thanks.

Comment: You know from calculus that $f(x) = \log(\frac{1}{1-x})$ for $0 < x < 2$ and therefore $\textrm{exp}(f(x)) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for such $x$.  Then it holds for all $z \in D$ by the identity principle.

Comment: The series of $\exp(z)$ has NOT radius of convergence $1$, it has radius of convergence $\infty$. You should check your "proof".

Comment: We could try doing this without knowledge of the function $\log$.  Can we combinatorially combine the power series to get this conclusion? That is, show 
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\right)^m
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k
$$An exercise in "generatingfunctionology".

Answer (score 2):

Continued comment.
We could try doing this without knowledge of the function $\log$.  Can we combinatorially combine the power series to get this conclusion? That is, show
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\right)^m
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k
$$An exercise in "generatingfunctionology".

---

Equivalent statement:  Fix a nonnegative integer $k$.  Consider all finite sequences
$(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_m)$ of positive integers with sum $k$.  Then
$$
\sum \frac{1}{m!n_1\cdots n_m} = 1
$$
summed over all those finite sequences.

For example, if $k=3$, then the possibilities are:
$3, 2+1, 1+2, 1+1+1$, and
$$
\frac{1}{1! \cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2!\cdot 2\cdot 1}
+\frac{1}{2!\cdot 1\cdot 2}+ \frac{1}{3!\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}
=
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6} = 1
$$
Can you do this for all $k$?
\begin{align}
k=0:&\qquad \frac{1}{0!} = 1
\\
k=1:&\qquad \frac{1}{1!\cdot 1} = 1
\\
k=2:&\qquad \frac{1}{1!\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2!\cdot1\cdot1} = 1
\end{align}

Comment: I added tags `combinatorics` and `integer-partitions`.